# Why Do I Get SQL Syntax Errors In My Query?

Tags: sql

I am trying to retrieve data in the following format:

```
Story | Story Type | Creation Date | Company Role | Tag 1 | Tag 2 | Tag 3
negative iii | Negative | 21/02/2011 | Business Analyst | Project Duration | Team Size | Process 
negative ccc | Negative | 22/02/2011 | Admin | Workspace Layout | Organisational | Process
```

instead of:

```
Story | StoryCategoryID | CreationDate | CompanyRole | Name  
negative iii | 1 | 21/02/2011 | Business Analyst | Project Duration 
negative iii | 1 | 21/02/2011 | Business Analyst | Team Size 
negative iii | 1 | 21/02/2011 | Business Analyst | Process 
negative ccc | 1 | 22/02/2011 | Admin | Workspace Layout 
negative ccc | 1 | 22/02/2011 | Admin | Organisational and Reporting Structure    
negative ccc | 1 | 22/02/2011 | Admin | Process
```

But am getting the following errors:

1) Incorrect syntax near keyword AS,

2) Incorrect syntax near Z

Here's my SQL, please help!

```
SELECT   
    Story, 
    CASE StoryCategoryID
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Negative'
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Positive' 
        ELSE CAST(StoryCategoryID as varchar(10)) as StoryCategoryID, 
     CreationDate, 
     CompanyRole, 
     MAX(CASE WHEN Z.MinName = af2.Name THEN af2.Name ELSE '' END) as Tag1 , 
     MAX(CASE WHEN Z.MinName <> af2.Name AND Z.MaxName <> af2.Name THEN af2.Name ELSE '' END) as Tag2, 
     MAX(CASE WHEN Z.MaxName = af2.Name THEN af2.Name ELSE '' END) as Tag3 
FROM ( SELECT s.Story , s.StoryCategoryID , 
              CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), s.CreationDate,  103) AS CreationDate , 
              m.CompanyRole , af.AgileFactorID , MIN(af.Name) MinName , 
              MAX(af.Name) MaxName 
        FROM Story s 
        INNER JOIN ProjectIterationMember pm 
              ON pm.ProjectIterationMemberID = s.ProjectIterationMemberID  
        INNER JOIN Iterations i     
              ON i.ProjectIterationID = pm.ProjectIterationID 
        INNER JOIN Member m  ON m.MemberID = pm.MemberID 
        INNER JOIN ProjectStoryFactors psf ON psf.StoryID = s.StoryID 
        INNER JOIN AgileFactors af ON af.AgileFactorID = psf.AgileFactorID 

        WHERE i.ProjectID = '" + proj_id + "'" 
        GROUP BY s.Story, 
                 s.StoryCategoryID, 
                 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), s.CreationDate, 103),   
                 m.CompanyRole, af.AgileFactorID ) Z 
  INNER JOIN AgileFactors af2  ON af2.AgileFactorID = Z.AgileFactorID 
  GROUP BY Story, StoryCategoryID, CreationDate, CompanyRole
```

Comment: can you whitespace format that SQL and repost?

Comment: Have u tried indenting your code and commenting out blocks to narrow down the location of the error?

Answer (score 4):

That SQL is unreadable:

```
SELECT   
Story, 
CASE StoryCategoryID WHEN 1 THEN 'Negative' WHEN 0 THEN 'Positive' 
ELSE CAST(StoryCategoryID as varchar(10)) as StoryCategoryID, 
CreationDate, 
CompanyRole, 
MAX(CASE WHEN Z.MinName = af2.Name THEN af2.Name ELSE '' END) as Tag1 , 
MAX(CASE WHEN Z.MinName <> af2.Name AND Z.MaxName <> af2.Name THEN af2.Name 
ELSE '' END) as Tag2, 
MAX(CASE WHEN Z.MaxName = af2.Name THEN af2.Name ELSE '' END) as Tag3 
FROM ( SELECT   s.Story , s.StoryCategoryID , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), s.CreationDate, 
103) AS CreationDate , 
m.CompanyRole , af.AgileFactorID , MIN(af.Name) MinName , 
MAX(af.Name) MaxName FROM Story s 
INNER JOIN ProjectIterationMember pm ON pm.ProjectIterationMemberID = 
s.ProjectIterationMemberID  INNER JOIN Iterations i     
ON i.ProjectIterationID = pm.ProjectIterationID INNER JOIN Member m     
ON m.MemberID = pm.MemberID INNER JOIN ProjectStoryFactors psf     
ON psf.StoryID = s.StoryID INNER JOIN AgileFactors af     
ON af.AgileFactorID = psf.AgileFactorID WHERE i.ProjectID = '" + proj_id + "'" 
GROUP BY s.Story, s.StoryCategoryID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), s.CreationDate, 103),   
m.CompanyRole, af.AgileFactorID ) Z INNER JOIN AgileFactors af2     
ON af2.AgileFactorID = Z.AgileFactorID 
GROUP BY Story, StoryCategoryID, CreationDate, CompanyRole;
```

At least organize it so the structural keywords are visible:

```
SELECT Story, 
       CASE StoryCategoryID WHEN 1 THEN 'Negative' WHEN 0 THEN 'Positive' 
       ELSE CAST(StoryCategoryID as varchar(10)) as StoryCategoryID, 
       CreationDate, 
       CompanyRole, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Z.MinName = af2.Name THEN af2.Name ELSE '' END) as Tag1, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Z.MinName <> af2.Name AND Z.MaxName <> af2.Name
           THEN af2.Name ELSE '' END) as Tag2, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Z.MaxName = af2.Name THEN af2.Name ELSE '' END) as Tag3 
  FROM (SELECT s.Story, s.StoryCategoryID,
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), s.CreationDate, 103) AS CreationDate, 
               m.CompanyRole, af.AgileFactorID, MIN(af.Name) MinName, 
               MAX(af.Name) MaxName
          FROM Story s 
          JOIN ProjectIterationMember pm
            ON pm.ProjectIterationMemberID = s.ProjectIterationMemberID
          JOIN Iterations i ON i.ProjectIterationID = pm.ProjectIterationID
          JOIN Member m     ON m.MemberID = pm.MemberID
          JOIN ProjectStoryFactors psf  ON psf.StoryID = s.StoryID
          JOIN AgileFactors af ON af.AgileFactorID = psf.AgileFactorID
         WHERE i.ProjectID = '" + proj_id + "'" 
         GROUP BY s.Story, s.StoryCategoryID,
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), s.CreationDate, 103),   
               m.CompanyRole, af.AgileFactorID) Z
  JOIN AgileFactors af2 ON af2.AgileFactorID = Z.AgileFactorID 
 GROUP BY Story, StoryCategoryID, CreationDate, CompanyRole
```

The notation `'" + proj_id + "'"` suggests this was extracted from a string in a programming language; it is an open invitation to SQL injection.  In a pure SQL context, it is syntactically invalid; you have a stray double quote at the end.

Answer (score 1):

what @JonathanLeffler said. <strike>Plus you're also missing commas:</strike>

<strike>MIN(af.Name) MinName ,</strike>

and

MAX(af.Name) MaxName <sub>Time to turn off the mac and go to bed :-o</sub>

Comment: Sorry red herring on my part - my eyes were scrambled after editing the code in your original post :-o

Comment: If the syntax is fine, then why am I getting those 2 errors? There is a problem near Z and AS...

Comment: I think Jonathan pointed out an issue with a double quote near _projid_? Have u corrected that? incidentally, the error checking output wrt line numbers should be taken with a pinch of salt, ur issue could be anywhere. Try commenting out blocks e.g the inner select etc. And see what runs in isolation.

Comment: If you're still stuck with this, how about posting your table definition(s)?